# Where does Kubernetes download image to?

Tags: kubernetes

I've read through [this page](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/images/) and I'm interested in where Kubernetes downloads an image to and how long it stores it for.

For example, let's say we have a large 3GB image. When i start up a pod will the image be downloaded to disk of the node the pod is being deployed to, and remain until that node is destroyed? If so does that mean i could allocate only 400MB of memory to a pod that is using a 3GB image?

Comment: Kubernetes does not, it's CRI that does. So then the question is "wherever your CRI is configured to store/download it".

Comment: We use EKS. I believe EKS is moving to `containerd` from its current default of `dockerd`. If i'm reading https://eksctl.io/usage/container-runtime/ correctly

Comment: Yes, container Images are stored on disk (e.g. for docker: https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/ and some info on containerd https://github.com/containerd/containerd/blob/main/docs/ops.md#base-configuration) so you will need 3GB free to deploy the container and as much memory as it takes for the software to run. But image size and memory requirements are in no way tied together. And they do stay at least until it's done running or the container would suddenly have no more filesystem to run from

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments correctly ,CRI does this rather than K8s, Assuming you are running Docker
If you want to access the image data directly, it’s usually stored in the following locations:

Linux: /var/lib/docker/

Windows: C:ProgramDataDockerDesktop

macOS: ~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/vms/0/

Answer (score 0):

If you are using containerd as runtime then the images are stored at /var/lib/containerd

it is configured in /etc/containerd/config.toml as shown below

[image]

contianerd runtime is responsible for downoading and running container using the image.
[image]